# Function of user-control type in a master page

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I have a user control file called `lcont.ascx`.  This `lcont` has been dragged into the master page.

Now I want to make a public function of type `lcont` in the master page, but `masterpage.cs` does not recognize `lcont` (saying `the type or namespace lcont couldnt be found(are you missing a using directive or reference) when I build).

Why?  I used this approach previously, and it worked.

Here's my master page:

```
<%@ Register src="Usercontrol/lcont.ascx" tagname="lcont" tagprefix="uc1" %>

 <div class="container" >
<form id="form1" runat="server">

<div class=" row ">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
     <uc3:Header ID="Header1" runat="server" />
  </div>
  </div>

        <div class="col-lg-3" style=" background:rgb(245,245,245); margin-right:1%; min-height:500px; " >
          <uc1:lcont ID="lcont1" runat="server" />
        </div>
```

Here's its code behind:

```
public lcont getlcont()
{
    return lcont1;
}
```

Actually what I want is to access the user control's ID in the ASPX page.  The user control is of course included in the master page.  Besides this, what else do I need to get around this problem?

Comment: How does the master page not 'recognize' lcont? Do you get an exception?

Comment: Exactly that's my point...how can a master page not recognize lcont.When i compile it says `the type or namespace lcont couldnt be found(are you missing a using directive or reference)`.The intresting thing however is that it shows `UserControl_lcont` by the inteligence when i type lcont when there is no `UserControl_lcont` defined anywhere.Does it differe if i am choosing to do the project as `web` or `project`.

Comment: Did you build the solution after creating the user control?

Comment: Yes i had built the solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have implemented `lcont` in the master page, you surely can make the public function
of the type `lcont`.

The way you are doing it is absolutely correct - exactly how it should be done.

So as far as I know, I think the problem is in the user control's class name.  The `lcont` you have used in the public function should be the class name of the `lcont` user control; but sometimes the class name is not the user control's file name.  I mean if your file name is `lcont.ascx`, you assume that the class name is `lcont` - in which case your code will work; but sometimes the class name is `foldername_usercontrolfilename` - in which case your code won't work.

So what should be done?

1. Check the first line of the `lcont.ascx` page.  There is a property called `Inherit`.  Check its value, which should be `lcont` not `foldername_lcont`.
2. Check the class declaration in the `lcont.ascx.cs` file.  It is probably `public partial class foldername_lcont : System.Web.UI.UserControl`.  Change it to `public partial class lcont : System.Web.UI.UserControl`.

Now your master page will recognize `lcont`.

For more on this, see https://unschoolingcode.wordpress.com/2014/10/16/accessing-usercontrols-id-in-the-aspx-page/